# Why is T a type projection of this.type in expanded type designator C.this.type#T

Tags: scala, types, terminology

[SLS 3.2.5 Type Designators](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#type-designators) indicates

```
trait C {
  type T
  val x: T
}
```

expands to

```
trait C {
  type T
  val x: C.this.type#T
}
```

I am familiar with `.type` notation in singleton types, but I am not sure how it translates to `C.this.type#T`. For example. what is `this.type` part trying to convey over just saying `C#T`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala specification primary concept is type projection rather than path-dependent type.

And path-dependent types are defined in terms of type projections (and singleton types).

For example for `val c: C` type `c.T` is `c.type#T` by definition.

And `c.x` has type `c.T` aka `c.type#T`.

Inside trait `C` such type (when instance `c` is not fixed) can be referred as `T` aka `this.T` aka `this.type#T` aka `C.this.T` aka `C.this.type#T`.